# Validate a child hidden form on load of parent form

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm having trouble validating a child component when it's hidden.

I have a generalized child component form that can be toggled `show` or `hidden`. On the parent form, I've used them 2 times because it's an address form, so a user can add a shipping address and billing address.

Both of the forms has it's own `save btn` to render the changes to the view but I want to save it or I want the `save btn` to be clickable if the form is valid. So I did this on the HTML file `parentForm.get('addressForm').valid` but then upon loading, I get the error because I think the address form hasn't been loaded or shown in the view I also think Angular removes the actual DOM.

```
<form [formGroup]="parentForm">

<div class="m-3 w-75 m-auto ">

          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <h4>Shipping Address</h4>
          <div>
           <button
              *ngIf="isEditingShippingAddress"
              class="btn btn-primary-invert mr-2"
              type="button"
              (click)="showHideForms(false, 'shippingAddress')"
           >
              Cancel
           </button>
           <button
             *ngIf="!isEditingShippingAddress"
              class="btn btn-primary-invert ml-2"
              type="button"
              (click)="showHideForms(false, 'shippingAddress')"
           >
              Edit
           </button>
           <button
              [disabled]="parentForm.get('addressForm').valid"
              *ngIf="isEditingShippingAddress"
              class="btn btn-primary-invert ml-2"
              type="submit"
            (click)="showHideForms(true, 'shippingAddress')"
           >
         Save
      </button>
   </div>

   // here's the child form !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
   <app-form-address
       *ngIf="isEditingShippingAddress; else shippingAddressTemplate"
            [parentForm]="form"
   >
   </app-form-address>

</form>
```

Check out the `save` btn (last button tag) that's the error coming from. Is there a fix for this? I also tried doing safe-navigation, no luck still.

### Edit

For those who are asking about the error message here it is:

`Cannot read property 'valid' of null`

Here's another error if you put safe navigation

`[disabled]="form?.get('bill_address_attributes')?.invalid"`

`ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'disabled: null'. Current value: 'disabled: true'.`

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: @wctiger something about `null invalid`

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your .ts file where you have declared "parentForm".

If you are getting error as cannot read address of undefined or valid of undefined try this==> [disabled]="parentForm?.get('addressForm')?.valid"

Comment: Aandy, you can not use [disabled] in a ReactiveForm. you need use a directive to disabled or use control.disable() –

Comment: I tried safe-navigation. still doesnt work. i dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

A control is always validated if it's disabled(*) (Angular not check a disabled control). You can disabled the child.

In [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) You has two aproach, well really you can remove the validators too or others options:

1. Disabled and hide the control using "display:none" (not *ngIf)
2. Use (change) to "disabled" enabled the control and use *ngIf

If you get the first approach, using disabled and hide. Create a directive and your form can be like

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="hideSurname">Hide surname
<form *ngIf="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm">
  <input formControlName="name">
  <input formControlName="surname" 
         [disableControl]="hideSurname" 
         [style.display]="hideSurname?'none':display" >
  </form>
```

If you get the second approach your form can be like

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="hideSurname2" (ngModelChange)="toogle($event)">Hide surname
<form *ngIf="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm">
  <input formControlName="name">
  <input *ngIf="!hideSurname2" formControlName="surname">
  </form>
```

Your function toogle must be like

```
toogle(value:boolean)
  {
    this.hideSurname2=value;
    if (this.hideSurname2)
      this.myForm2.get('surname').disable();
    else
      this.myForm2.get('surname').enable();
  }
```

(*) Using Angular 7 -I think that in Angular 4 not work the same way